# R shiny bookmark bucket lists

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to achieve persistent data storage of R Shiny inputs via a bookmarking method. However, I am unable to retain data related to bucket lists.

If, for example, I begin with the following code, and transfer n items to the second bucket list, the input is not stored. How could I rectify this? Thank you.

```
library(shiny)

ui <-   fluidPage( bucket_list(
  header = "This is a bucket list. You can drag items between the lists.",
  add_rank_list(
    text = "Drag from here",
    labels = c("a", "bb", "ccc")
  ),
  add_rank_list(
    text = "to here",
    labels = NULL
  )
),
bookmarkButton())

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

enableBookmarking(store = "url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal example above is missing a few bits. Below is a minimal example showing bookmarking used to persistently store selections.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) {
    
    fluidPage(
        textInput("txt", "Text"),
        checkboxInput("chk", "Checkbox"),
        bookmarkButton()
    )
    
}

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
    
}

enableBookmarking("url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Bucket lists don't appear to be natively supported by bookmarks. You can manually store and retrieve data from bookmarks using `onBookmark` and `onRestore` and then `renderUI` to update your bucket list.

---

Edit: Additional example showing the use of `onBookmark` and `onRestore` and then `renderUI` to get bucket lists working with bookmarks.

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- function(request) {
    
    fluidPage(

        uiOutput("bucket"),
        bookmarkButton()
        
    )
    
}

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
    
    output$bucket <- renderUI({
        
        bucket_list(
            header = "This is a bucket list. You can drag items between the lists.",
            add_rank_list(
                text = "Drag from here",
                labels = c("a", "bb", "ccc"),
                input_id = 'list1'
            ),
            add_rank_list(
                text = "to here",
                labels = NULL,
                input_id = 'list2'
            )
        )
        
    })
    
    #When creating a bookmark, manually store the selections from our bucket lists
    onBookmark(function(state) {
        
        state$values$list1 <- input$list1
        state$values$list2 <- input$list2
    })
    
    #When restoring a bookmark, manually retrieve the selections from our bucket lists and re-render the bucket list input
    onRestore(function(state) {
      
        output$bucket <- renderUI({
            
            bucket_list(
                header = "This is a bucket list. You can drag items between the lists.",
                add_rank_list(
                    text = "Drag from here",
                    labels = state$values$list1,
                    input_id = 'list1'
                ),
                add_rank_list(
                    text = "to here",
                    labels = state$values$list2,
                    input_id = 'list2'
                )
            )
            
        })
        
    })
    
}

enableBookmarking("url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ash. I have other sections (e.g checkboxInput) that bookmark OK.